# Mongoose lowercase option doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the mongoose framework and trying to insert data. This is my schema:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "gender": {
        type: String,
        enum: ["male", "female", "other", "unknown"],
        lowercase: false,
    },
    ...
});
```

I only want to allow case-sensitive values of the name. So the dataset `{"gender":"Male"}` should create an error. But in fact, it doesn't matter if I use `lowercase: true` or false, it creates the Object and uses the lowercase value of my enum. Only when I delete the `lowercase` attribute, then my inserted dataset isn't accepted.

Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: What was wrong with the behavior you got when removing `lowercase` attribute?

Comment: The main problem is, that I want to set this value per config file.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Why is it not okay what happens if you just remove `lowercase`?

Comment: In some cases `lowercase` should be tru, in some not (depending on the users config). I have to set the value.

Comment: i dont think you can achieve that. What you can do is to store both config and value as either lowercase or capital and when you fetch it "translate" per config. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Oh, I see. `lowercase` doesn't work as a validator. What it does, is that it converts the value to lowercase before saving:
"lowercase: boolean, whether to always call .toLowerCase() on the value" http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: I've already implemented that the value for `lowercase` is read from a config file. But this isn't the problem here. The problem is, that the function does not work and will always adjust it to lowercase, no matter if it is set to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this is apperently a bug from mongoose. I created a bug report on GitHub: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4622